# Where can I find topology-related algorithms used in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, topology

I have shapefile with polygons and I test topology - overlaps, duplicates and gaps. I tested it in QGIS and now I have to describe algorithms, which uses QGIS for this rules. I must write research algorithms.
I finded just general description:
http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/topology.html
and
http://qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html
but I can´t find algorithms.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried, what you have found online and what *exactly* that you need assistance with?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS code is hosted on Github. I suggest you start your search there, e.g. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?p=2&q=topology&ref=cmdform

If you know exactly which tool you want to research, it should be easier to find the corresponding piece of code.